# Python -- row[2] in matrix, encryption function

Tags: python, matrix, row

I am trying to understand how to define a row or column in the matrix in the following code.

```
#Columnar Transposition
import math
  
key = "BCA"
  
#Encryption
def encryptMessage(msg):
    cipher = ""
  
    # track key indices
    k_indx = 0
  
    msg_len = float(len(msg))
    msg_lst = list(msg)
    key_lst = sorted(list(key))
  
    # calculate column of the matrix
    col = len(key)
      
    # calculate maximum row of the matrix
    row = int(math.ceil(msg_len / col))
  
    # add the padding character '_' in empty
    # the empty cell of the matix 
    fill_null = int((row * col) - msg_len)
    msg_lst.extend('_' * fill_null)
  
    # create Matrix and insert message and 
    # padding characters row-wise 
    matrix = [msg_lst[i: i + col] 
              for i in range(0, len(msg_lst), col)]
  
    # read matrix column-wise using key
    for _ in range(col):
        curr_idx = key.index(key_lst[k_indx])
        cipher += ''.join([row[curr_idx] 
                          for row in matrix])
        k_indx += 1
  
    return cipher

#Driver Code
msg = "I am amazing"

cipher = encryptMessage(msg)
print("Encrypted Message: {}".
           format(cipher))
```

Here is the part of the code I can't fully understand.
How is the code `cipher += ''.join([row[curr_idx] for row in matrix])` can achieving adding column together if I give a number 2 on row[2]? For my own understanding, row[2] will indicate add the 2nd rows together which is `"zin"`, not the columns.

Let say `curr_idx = 2`, and I have a table below.

```
| C | B | A |
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| I | a | m |
| a | m | a |
| z | i | n |
| g | _ | _ |
```

So the logic of this encrypted is to:
1st write the keyword which is "CBA" and then order the keyword base on the alphabet order from A to Z, in this case, C = 3(position 0), B = 2(position 1), and A = 1(position 2).  
2nd eliminate the space in original plaintext and write in row-wise order under the keyword table.
3rd Then read the cipher textbase column-wise order starts from 1.
For the example input `"I am amazing"`. The complete ciphertext for this example is `"man_ami_Iazg"`

I understand the correct output will be `"man_"` for `row[2]`, 2 indicate A's position because we need to read starts from A column.

But why row[2] is not the output of "zin" instead it did the function print out the column under position index 2, which is `A` here?

Comment: Can you initialize `matrix` to make this a running example? Is this is a list of lists?

Comment: Why would the output be `"man_"` for `curr_idx = 2` and not `"Aman_"`? Your code is grabing the `curr_idx`th item from each row in your matrix so `"man_"` is not a possible output unless you have other code you're not showing.

Comment: If you have a list of lists, then `list_of_lists[2]` would indeed give you `["z", "i", "n"]` but it's not possible at the moment to determine what the problem is exactly as you haven't provided enough detail, code, or sample data.

Comment: If you don't tell us what `matrix` is, how can we answer this question? Post a working script, that will answer the question. Its easy.

Comment: @tdelaney Thank you for your feedback, I am brand new in Python since it is just to pick up one of my encryption assignments and Prof let me use Python. I am able to customize the code but I do want to have a full understanding of it. I did a couple of searches on Google about the row() python but can't see the answer.

Comment: @ddejohn Actually I am brand new in Python... and I try to figure out this code for a week only stuck in the Highline code. I have included the full code in it. I am not actually understanding list_of_lists[2] but for matrix() and row() function example I searched on Google, it did look like row[2] will return in column order, I just don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

After days of researching and helping from friends.
Those 2 line codes can actually rephrase as below:

```
  for row in matrix:
        cipher += ''.join([row[curr_idx])
```

Then the matrix should looks like `[["I"," ","a"],["m"," ","a"],["m","a","z"],["i","n","g"]]`

So row[2] indicate to take each nest list position 2 which is `a` in `["I"," ","a"]`, `a` in `["m"," ","a"]`, `z` in `["m","a","z"]` and `g` in `["i","n","g"]`.

The result will be `"aazg"` in this `row[2]` case.